# conditional copying in excel

Tags: excel, vba

hi
i need some help with vba.

i know that when you want to copy excel cells based on a condition, you do so by right clicking the sheet and entering the visual basic screen.

thing is, i'm not very familiarized with vb. i've read some similar posts but haven't been able to understand them completely.

this is what i want to do:
i'm making a workbook for chemistry students to illustrate surface tension. what i did was give them 5 different substances to choose from.

i already have data from reliable sources, so calculations are not a problem.
thing is, i want to display the results on graphs. i only want them to choose 2 different substances at a time, so i only want to display 2 graphs.

i don't know how to copy the data from the substances they chose.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can help you; you need to be more specific. If I understand your question, you have a graph that plots data from one sheet (sheet A), another sheet that contains all the data (sheet B), and you want sheet A to contain some of the data from sheet B, based on a condition specified in sheet A (ie, type of substance) and reload the data in sheet A with some data from sheet B based on an event that triggers the moving of the data. Is this about right? If so, I need to know the following.

1) where is the data stored in sheet A to generate the graph
2) is the data the same lenght (ie. all 5 substance data contain 50 rows, for example)
3) what's the trigger to change graph and start the procedure to move data around
4) how is the data stored in sheet B
5) what is the condition
6) what's the trigger

It'd be nice if you could post your spreadsheet online somewhere.